# How to export the results of ListDataProvider to excel in GWT

Tags: java, excel, gwt

I am using ListDataProvider to handle data in my celltable and I want to export everything int he listdataprovider to the excel sheet. Currently I am using https://code.google.com/p/gwt-table-to-excel/ plugin, which export only the item in the table but I wants to export everything in the data provider. how can I do that or if there is any other method to export result in the excel sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing table page size.

CellTable has a "Constructs a table with the given page size".
http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge, there is no easy way to export data from the client as Excel.

One solution is to use a [POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/) API or any Java reporting API (example : Jasper report) in the backend and invoke it from the client.